# Find continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is differentiable everywhere except $ \forall c \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

> Find continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is differentiable everywhere except $\forall c \in \mathbb Z$

**Attempt:**

Let $$f(x) = \sqrt{1-\cos(2 \pi x)}$$
Then $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and is continuous everywhere.

$$f'(x) = \frac{\pi \sin(2 \pi x)}{\sqrt{1 - \cos(2 \pi x)}}$$

This is undefined $\forall c \in \mathbb Z$

However, since this is a case of $\frac00$, it seems necessary to me to observe the limiting behavior before I conclude it's undefined for all integers. A quick test on Mathematica showed that the left hand limit is $-\sqrt2 \pi$ and right hand limit is $\sqrt2 \pi$, so the limit does not exist. This should validate my function, however I'm still a little unsatisfied. First, is the function a valid candidate? second, how would I go about calculating that limit if so?

Comment: Far easier just to concatenate line segments, with corners at the integers. (A general problem-solving strategy: look for the simplest example first.)

Comment: That expression doesn't make sense. Just take $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend to the whole real line by setting $f(x+2)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Take the graph of $y=\sin 2 \pi x$ and rotate it $\pi / 4$ counterclockwise. The tangents at $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ will be vertical.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: I don't see how that would work, the range is finite and I need the function to map $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: The notation $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ does not mean the image/range of the function is the entire real line. It means only that the codomain is the real line. The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ has a finite range, too. If you want the image/range to be the whole real line, you need to add that to the question (e.g. by saying you want $f$ to be surjective).

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh okay, I was unaware that the notation meant that. What is the codomain, then? Does that just mean we're limiting the possible out-values to be real numbers?

Comment: $... vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ...$

Comment: @infinitylord: the notation $f:A\to B$ just means $f$ takes in values in $A$ and returns values in $B$. it does not mean every value in $B$ gets hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a sequence of semi-circles that are above the $x$-axis, but the diameters on the $x$-axis: each semicircle is of diameter  unit length starting at an integer point $(n,0)$ and ending at the next integer point $(n+1,0)$. Regard this as the graph of a function. Write down the formula for that function. It will meet your requirement.

Comment: I do like that idea. I feel that $|\sin(2 \pi x)|$ should do the trick rather well.

Comment: @infinitylord: you want $|\sin \pi x|$, not $|\sin 2\pi x|$. The latter has discontinuities at half-integers, too.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: Oh yes, very true. Good catch. Nevertheless, I feel that $|\sin(\pi x)| + x$ would work best to keep the range in-tact

Comment: This was going to my answer if I had seen this Q sooner. A variation of it enables us to construct a continuous f that is differentiable except on a given discrete set of 2 or more members.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $1 - \cos(2\pi x) = 2 \sin^2(px)$, therefore $f' = \frac{2\pi \sin(\pi x) \cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt{2} |\sin(\pi x)|} = \sqrt{2}\pi \cos(\pi x) \frac{\sin 2\pi x}{|\sin 2\pi x|}$, and the last factor is $\pm 1$ depending on which side you approach an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Take the function $f(x):=|x|$ $\ (-1\leq x\leq 1)$, extended periodically with period $2$ to all of ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x)=\sqrt{1-\cos x}$; then
$$
g'(x)=\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{1-\cos x}}
$$
for $x\ne 2k\pi$ ($k$ an integer). On the other hand
$$
\frac{g(2k\pi+h)-g(2k\pi)}{h}
=\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos h}}{h}=\frac{\lvert\sin h\rvert}{h}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos h}}
$$
so $g$ is not differentiable at $2k\pi$: the limit for $h\to0$ doesn't exist: it equals $-1/\sqrt{2}$ from the left and $1/\sqrt{2}$ from the right.

Now consider $f(x)=g(2\pi x)$. (Yes, it's exactly your idea.)